# Retrieve data from Parse and fill textfields

Tags: ios, parse-platform, textfield

I've used parse to set objects from three text fields in a view controller like so:

`PFObject *profile = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Profile"];
       [profile setObject:_setArtistName.text forKey:@"artistName"];
       [profile setObject:_setGenre.text forKey:@"genre"];
       [profile setObject:_setDescription.text forKey:@"description"];`

After hitting the 'submit' button, parse sets the objects. I'd like to know how to retrieve these objects in order to fill the same text fields, so when the user goes back to the view controller, the text fields are already filled in from the information he entered earlier.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [doc](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS):

If you have the objectId, you can retrieve the whole PFObject using a PFQuery. Replacing "xWMyZ4YEGZ" with your own objectId.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Profile"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"xWMyZ4YEGZ" block:^(PFObject *userProfile, NSError *error) {
    // Do something with the returned PFObject.
    NSLog(@"%@", userProfile);
}];
```